Are comprehensiveness and comprehension completely unrelated words?
Comprehensive : inclusive of everything. Exhaustive, complete.
Comprehension : Understanding and awareness.

Please check etymology :1)https://www.etymonline.com/word/comprehension#etymonline_v_28489  - 2)https://www.etymonline.com/word/comprehensive

And you'll see that they both come from the same Latin root via French: comprehendere "to take together, to unite; include; to comprehend, perceive" (to seize or take in the mind),

This question should not have been closed. It is an etymology question, not a mere dictionary question - its scope extends beyond basic meaning, pronunciation, and usage. The OP obviously understands the meaning of the words, etc - they state their meanings in the question.

Consulting a dictionary - as per Gio's comment above - will show the common origin.

These words are related. They are both derived from the Latin Comprehendere "to take together, to unite; include; to comprehend, perceive"
Comprehensive - Online Etymology Dictionary

...past participle stem of Latin comprehendere "to take together, to
unite; include; to comprehend, perceive"

Comprehension- Online Etymology Dictionary

...past participle stem of comprehendere "to take together, to unite;
include; to comprehend, perceive"

Cambridge Dictionary-Comprehensive means "complete and including everything that is necessary"
Cambridge Dictionary-Comprehension means "the ability to understand completely and be familiar with a situation, facts, etc."
These words share the notion of completeness/inclusiveness/unification: Comprehensive meaning the object includes/unites everything necessary for a subject.
Comprehension meaning one's knowledge and understanding include/unite all that is necessary for a subject.
